# Is the torsion subgroup the sum or the direct sum of $p$-primary components?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

This is written on Page 93 of Derek J.S. Robinson's *A Course in the Theory of Groups*:

> Let $G$ be an arbitrary abelian group, $T$ its torsion-subgroup. For an arbitray prime $p$, denote $G_p$ as the $p$-primary component of $G$. **Then $T$ is the sum of all the $G_p$**.

Isn't $T$ the *direct sum* of $G_p$? For any element $a \in T$, $a$ is of finite order. If the order of $a$ equals $p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k}$ where $p_i$'s are primes and $n_i$'s are positive integers. Then there must exist $a_i \in G_{p_i}$, $i=1, \cdots k$, such that $a = \sum_i a_i$. Because if $q \notin \{p_1, \cdots p_k \}$, and a nonzero $b \in G_q$ appears in the summation form of $a$, then the order of $a$ must be divisible by $q$. But in fact it isn't.

In my understanding, a direct sum is like the coproduct in category language, where every element written in the summation form has only finite nonzero components. But a *sum* can take the sum of infinitely many elements. In fact, picking infinitely elements of $G$, one per $G_p$, and adding them together may get an element of infinite order, lying outside $T$.

Where am I wrong?

---

Then I considered $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$. What is the sum of inverse of primes $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \cdots$? Is it still in $\mathbb{Q}$? The definition of a group $(G, *, 1)$ only says for finitely many $a_i \in G$, $a_1 * \cdots * a_n$ is in $G$; it doesn't guarantee the closedness of $G$ under infinitely many times of applying the operation $*$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a "sum of subgroups $H_i$" is the subgroup generated by the subgroups, which consists only of all *finite* sums of elements of $\cup H_i$; there is no such thing as "infinite sums" in general groups (you need some notion of convergence in order to talk about infinite sums).

In particular, the **abelian group** $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain infinite sums. With repeated application of a binary operation you can get sums with arbitrarily large *but finite* number of summands, not infinite sums/series.

---

There are two types of "direct sum". The so-called "External Direct Sum" (which is a subgroup of the direct product, etc), and the so-called "Internal Direct Sum".

An abelian group $G$ *is* the external direct sum of groups $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$ if $G$ is exactly the set of $I$-tuples, $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$, with almost all entries trivial.

If, on the other hand, $\{H_i\}_{i\in I}$ are a family of subgroups of $G$ such that $\sum H_i = G$ and $H_i\cap\left(\sum_{j\neq i}H_j\right)=\{0\}$, then $G$ is *isomorphic* to $\oplus H_i$, but is not actually *equal* to this direct sum. Then we say that $G$ is the *internal direct sum* of the $H_i$.

Technically, internal and external direct sums are different types of constructions. Morally and in practice, they are the same, because if $G$ is the internal direct sum of its subgroups $H_i$, then it is isomorphic to the external direct sum of the $H_i$; and the external direct sum of the $H_i$ is an internal direct sum of the subgroups $\mathcal{H}_i$, where $\mathcal{H}_i$ is the subgroup of all elements whose $j$th entries are equal to $0$ for all $j\neq i$. So in practice, the distinction is dropped.

Robinson is perfectly correct in saying that $T$ is the *sum* of the subgroups (i.e., the subgroup generated by them). You are, also, correct in noting that this sum is in fact "direct" (that is, that $T$ is the *internal* direct sum of the $p$-torsion parts of $G$). If a group is the internal direct sum of some subgroups, then it is also the sum of these subgroups (the converse does not hold, if there are intersections between the subgroups).

Comment: I misunderstood the term _sum_. Thank you very much for your perfect explanation!