# Direct sum of p-primary components for a torsion group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian torsion group. Now I want to show that $G=\bigoplus_{p\in\mathcal{P}}G(p)$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of all primes and $G(p)=\{i\in G:p^n=e\ \text{for some}\ n\ge 0\}$. I found an answer here:
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83823/is-the-torsion-subgroup-the-sum-or-the-direct-sum-of-p-primary-components), but I would like to know whether my method to this statement is correct. Here is my attempt:

By the fumdemental theorem of abelian groups and the fact that $G$ is torsion, we may let $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{n_1}}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p_2^{n_2}}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{n_k}}$, where $p_i$ are primes and $n_i$ are positive integers, $i=1,2,\cdots,k$. Now consider $G(p)$, it should have $G(p)\cong\bigoplus_{p=p_i}\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{n_i}}$, therefore we have
$$G\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{n_i}}\cong\bigoplus_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\bigoplus_{p=p_i}\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{a_i}}\cong\bigoplus_{p\in\mathcal{P}}G(p).$$

Is this method correct or I made some mistakes? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If by $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ you mean $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, then there's the slight mistake that $G$ doesn't have to be finite; take for instance the subgroup $\mu_\infty \leq \mathbb{C}^\times$ of the roots of unity, which is an abelian torsion group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of abelian groups only treats the case where the abelian group is finitely generated. Since this assumption isn't present in the statement to be proved, invoking this fundamental theorem isn't valid.